# NSArray retainCount

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, retaincount

I thought it would be printed in order 0-1->0. 
This output was strangely different results. (0->3->2)
Why is that?

ClassA.h :

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
{
    NSArray *array;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSArray *array;
@end
```

main.c

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
         ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc]init];
         NSLog(@"retainCount %lu", (unsigned long)[classA.array retainCount]);

         classA.array = [[NSArray alloc]init];
         NSLog(@"retainCount %lu", (unsigned long)[classA.array retainCount]);

         [classA.array release];
         NSLog(@"retainCount %lu", (unsigned long)[classA.array retainCount]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
2014-02-10 11:58:24.459 retainCount[4031:303] retainCount 0
2014-02-10 11:58:24.461 retainCount[4031:303] retainCount 3
2014-02-10 11:58:24.462 retainCount[4031:303] retainCount 2
```

Comment: [Here's why you shouldn't trust `retainCount`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784084/calling-retaincount-considered-harmful?rq=1)

Comment: in addition to above link: refer to the golden rules: "you don't have to release which you have not retained" and "release a variable that many times you have retained it"

Comment: Also check :[why can i send messages to a deallocated instance of nsarray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233853/why-can-i-send-messages-to-a-deallocated-instance-of-nsarray)